# MySQL Commands out of sync error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I am new to MySQL, normally use SQL Server. I have a MySQL server (version 5.1.73) and I have two databases, **syslog** and **syslog_archive**.

There are three tables:

- syslog.logs
- syslog_archive.logs
- syslog_archive.tmp_logs

When executing the below procedure, I receive the following error.

> Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

**Table Schema for all three tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `host` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facility` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stme` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `program` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stime` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`seq`),
  KEY `host` (`host`),
  KEY `program` (`program`),
  KEY `sdate` (`sdate`),
  KEY `stime` (`stme`),
  KEY `priority` (`priority`),
  KEY `facility` (`facility`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38500021 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Procedure Code:**

```
USE syslog_archive;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `spArchiveLogRecords`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spArchiveLogRecords
(
    retentionDays INT #Number of days of records to keep in the primary syslog database
    , batchSize INT #How many rows to process per batch
    , batchPause INT #How long to wait in between batches
)
spArchiveLogRecords_Label:BEGIN

    DECLARE retentionDaysChr VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE batchSizeChr VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE todayChr CHAR(10);
    DECLARE records INT;

    #Input validation
    IF (retentionDays < 0) THEN
        SELECT 'retentionDays must be a positive number.'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'No work has been conducted.';

        LEAVE spArchiveLogRecords_Label;
    END IF;
    IF (batchSize < 0) THEN
        SELECT 'batchSize must be a positive number.'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'No work has been conducted.';

        LEAVE spArchiveLogRecords_Label;
    END IF;
    IF (batchPause < 0) THEN
        SELECT 'batchPause must be a positive number.'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'No work has been conducted.';

        LEAVE spArchiveLogRecords_Label;
    END IF;

    #Variable initialization
    SET todayChr = CAST(CURDATE() AS CHAR(10));
    SET retentionDaysChr := RTRIM(CAST(retentionDays AS CHAR(10))); 
    SET batchSizeChr := RTRIM(CAST(batchSize AS CHAR(10)));   

    SET @sqlText = CONCAT("INSERT INTO syslog_archive.tmp_logs
                    ( `host`, facility, priority, `level`, tag
                    , sdate, stme, program, msg, seq, stime )
                    SELECT l.`host`, l.facility, l.priority, l.`level`, l.tag
                    , l.sdate, l.stme, l.program, l.msg, l.seq, l.stime
                    FROM syslog.logs l  
                    LEFT JOIN syslog_archive.logs al ON l.seq = al.seq  
                    WHERE l.sdate <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL ",retentionDaysChr," DAY 
                        AND al.seq IS NULL  
                    LIMIT ",batchSizeChr);

    #debugging
    #SELECT @sqlText;
    #end debugging 

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

    batch_loop : LOOP

        #Truncate stage
        TRUNCATE TABLE syslog_archive.tmp_logs;

        #Load stage from primary
        PREPARE stageStmt FROM @sqlText;   
        EXECUTE stageStmt;
        SET records := FOUND_ROWS();
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stageStmt;

        IF (records = 0) THEN
            LEAVE batch_loop;
        END IF;

        START TRANSACTION;

            #Insert into archive
            INSERT INTO syslog_archive.logs
            ( 
                `host`, facility, priority, `level`, tag
                , sdate, stme, program, msg, seq, stime 
            )
            SELECT `host`, facility, priority, `level`, tag
                , sdate, stme, program, msg, seq, stime 
            FROM syslog_archive.tmp_logs;

            #Oddly, table aliases broke the query with an
            #Unknown table 'l' in MULTI DELETE
            #error message.
            DELETE syslog.logs
            FROM syslog.logs 
            INNER JOIN syslog_archive.tmp_logs 
                ON syslog_archive.tmp_logs.seq = syslog.logs.seq;

        COMMIT;

        #debugging
        #LEAVE batch_loop;
        #end debugging

        SELECT SLEEP(batchPause);        

    END LOOP;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL spArchiveLogRecords(1, 100000, 2);
```

Comment: It appears to get through multiple iterations of the LOOP before throwing the error.

Comment: I read this post but do not think it is relevant since I am not passing in any NULL seq values. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/mysql-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably among

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,370578 (Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,591655 (2014 - commands out of sync; you can't run this command now)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,419733 (stored procedure issue in php script)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,407069 (ERROR 2014: "Commands out of sync;" when doing a SELECT After CALL)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,406327 (After execution of stored procedure output is [BLOB - 0B])
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,386018 (How to do stored procedure return multiple rows ?)